# Cohomology ring of classifying space of spin group $\mathrm{BSpin}(n)$

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, cohomology

$\DeclareMathOperator\BSpin{BSpin}\DeclareMathOperator\Pin{Pin}\DeclareMathOperator\BSO{BSO}\DeclareMathOperator\BO{BO}\DeclareMathOperator\BPin{BPin}$In the answer for question: [Homology of classifying space of spin group BSpin(n)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/114948),
it was shown that $H_i(\BSpin(\infty),\mathbb{Z})$ is $0,0,0,\mathbb{Z}$, for $i=1,2,3,4$. Here I like ask a more detailed question:

- **What is the cohomology ring $H^*(\BSpin(\infty),Z)$?**

Also what is cohomology rings $H^i(\BPin^\pm(\infty),Z)$ (where $\Pin^\pm (n)$ is a $\Pin^\pm$ group)?

This paper

- D.J. Benson and Jay A. Wood, *Integral invariants and cohomology of $\BSpin(n)$*, Topology **34** Issue 1 (1995) pp 13–28, doi:[10.1016/0040-9383(94)E0019-G](https://doi.org/10.1016/0040-9383%2894%29E0019-G),

does not give an explicit result.

I cannot find a digital copy of

- E. Thomas, *On the cohomology groups of the classifying space for the stable spinor group*, Bol. Sot. Mat. Mexicana (2) 7 (1962), 57-69.

For $\BSO(n)$, this paper

- Edgar H. Brown, Jr., *The Cohomology of $\BSO_n$ and $\BO_n$ with Integer Coefficients*, Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society
  Vol. 85, No. 2 (1982), pp. 283-288, doi:[10.2307/2044298](https://doi.org/10.2307/2044298),

provides a full answer.

Comment: Here is some result but with different coefficients https://arxiv.org/pdf/0704.4002.pdf  .You need it for metaplectic quantification?

Comment: I need the results for understanding topological orders in fermion systems.

Comment: May you add some motivation for your question

Comment: See https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0124.16401 if you click on "Show Scanned Page" , you can find all other pages

Comment: [See also Kono's paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/kyoto-journal-of-mathematics/volume-26/issue-3/On-the-integral-cohomology-of-BSpinn/10.1215/kjm/1250520870.full)

Answer (score 8):

- Haibao Duan, *The characteristic classes and Weyl invariants of Spinor groups*, https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.03799

This recent paper gives a clean answer for your question. In particular, it provides the so-called spin classes, with explicit relations to Pontryagin classes and Stiefel-Whiteny classes